# Twilio: How to initiate a flow with an API call

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-studio

I'm trying to initiate a flow on Twilio via an API call in Node, and I can't seem to get it to work. The flow is designed to make an outbound call when the API request is sent. Have tried several code examples I've seen online to no avail. I'm getting an error like `Cannot read property X of undefined` (see below), but the thing is I'm able to initiate a phone call (not a flow, just a call) to my cell phone via an API call, so I know the Twilio client is connected.

Works:

```
app.post('/call', (req, res) => {
  client.calls
  .create({
     url: 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/PNxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     to: '+1708xxxxxxx',
     from: '+1312xxxxxxx'
   })
  .then((call, err) => {
      if (err) { console.log(err) }
      res.json({ success: "success" });
    });
  });
```

Not working: Triggers `Cannot read property 'v1' of undefined`

```
app.post('/flow', (req, res) => {

    client.studio.v1.flows('FWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    .fetch()
    .then(flow => console.log("flow : ", flow));
```

Not working: Triggers `Cannot read property 'flows' of undefined`

```
app.post('/flow', (req, res) => {
  client.studio.flows('FWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
  .executions
  .create({
    to: '+1847xxxxxxx',
    from: '+1312xxxxxxx'
  })
  .then(function(execution) { console.log("sid : ", execution.sid); });
});
```

Not working: No error, just nothing happens

```
app.post('/flow', (req, res) => {

  client.calls
  .create({
    url: 'https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Executions',
    to: '+1847xxxxxxx',
    from: '+1312xxxxxxx'
  })
  .then((call, err) => {
    if (err) { console.log("err : ", err) }
    if (call) { console.log("call : ", call)}
    res.json({ success: "success" });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that you're using an old version of Twilio's Node.js library without support for Studio flows. The current version is `3.39.1`

You can find the version you're using if you read "dependencies" in the package.json file.

Also, if you open a terminal in your project root folder and run `npm outdated` you'll probably see twilio colored red in that table.

---

**How to fix:**

There might be other ways to do this but to get the latest version just for Twilio's package I would open a terminal in the project's root folder and

- run `npm uninstall twilio --save`
- then run `npm install twilio --save`

After that check again with `npm list --depth=0` and hopefully you'll get `-- twilio@3.39.1` which has support for Studio flows.

Comment: Also weird that in my `package.json` I had `"twilio": "^4.6.0"`, but had to go backward to `3.39.1`, but it's at least working

Comment: Without seeing your flow, probably you're making an http request in your flow after the call. Try with a minimal flow which only makes a voice call then add to it more things step by step to find where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node

I would install the twilio into your project.

From console -This adds the packages into your package.json and downloads the modules
`npm install --save twilio`

````
var accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = 'your_auth_token';   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
    body: 'Hello from Node',
    to: '+12345678901',  // Text this number
    from: '+12345678901' // From a valid Twilio number
})
.then((message) => console.log(message.sid));```


when using the twilio node package they also have info on making calls with it
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/node
````

```
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
// DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
      .create({
         url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
         to: '+123456789',
         from: '+987654321'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

Comment: Already installed in my project, That's how the `/call` url is working. But the `/flow` one isn't.

Comment: Where did the studio.v1 come from? I can't find that in their documentation.

Comment: This page: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution